# Python using pymysql fails to add a field to a table in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

```
When I use python to apply the pymysql module to add a field to a table in the mysql database, it does not return failure. However, when I query the database, I find that the new field is not displayed.
In addition, when I run the new field script again, it returns pymysql.err.InternalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'xxx xxx'")
```

The following is a new field script

```
import pymysql
textdb = {
    "host": "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "database": "textdbs",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "port": 3306,
    "charset": 'utf8'
}
db = pymysql.connect(**textdb)
course = db.cursor()
sql = "alter table `{}` add `{}` varchar(255) default NULL".format("table", "testund")
course.execute(sql)
```

This is a script applied to a remote database. At the beginning, I felt that there was a problem with the script. After doing experiments in the local database, I found that the fields can be added normally.

Answer (score 0):

add `course.commit()` after `course.executr(sql)`

Comment: I tried doing this and found that no new fields were added, and when I was experimenting locally, I could add new fields without adding course.commit ().

Comment: sytax seems to be wrong use these.

`sql = "alert table table_name add column column_name  varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL"
course.execute(sql)
`